# Split a matrix by value in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, split

I wonder if there is a MATLAB solution to split a matrix into sub matrices like the following:

The matrix is:

```
A =
16     2    3
5      11   10
9      7    6
4      14   15
5      1    3
```

I would like to take the rows that are starting with 5 to another matrix, those that start with 16 to another, etc..

Is there a function for this or should I go with if/for approach?

Comment: Matlab should always be programmed with vector operations when possible, but I don't see a way around `for` and `if` is this case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one solution that uses the functions [SORTROWS](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/sortrows.html), [UNIQUE](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/unique.html), [ACCUMARRAY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/accumarray.html), and [MAT2CELL](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mat2cell.html) to create a cell array with each cell storing a set of rows with the same value in the first column:

```
>> sortedA = sortrows(A,1);  %# Sort the rows by the first column
>> [~,~,uniqueIndex] = unique(sortedA(:,1));  %# Find indices of unique values
                                              %#   in the first column
>> cellA = mat2cell(sortedA,...                       %# Break matrix up by rows
                    accumarray(uniqueIndex(:),1),3);  %#   into a cell array
>> cellA{:}  %# Display the contents of the cells

ans =

     4    14    15

ans =

     5    11    10
     5     1     3

ans =

     9     7     6

ans =

    16     2     3
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I found it = )

```
for n=1:max(max(A))
M{n} = A(find(A(:,1)==n),:);
end
```

Now `M{n}` is the matrix of all rows that start with `n`. = )